# Fast vectorized way of computing a pairwise delta kernel in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am interested in computing a 0-1 distance matrix where it is basically a "Dirac delta" kernel.

The requirements would be the following:

```
def delta_kernel(X, Y):
   """
   X : ndarray of shape (n_samples_x, n_features_x)
   Y : ndarray of shape (n_samples_y, n_features_y)
   Returns
   kernel_arr : ndarray of shape (n_samples_x, n_samples_y)
   """
   # compute pairwise kernel, where the kernel_arr[i, j] == 1 if 
   # X[i, :] == Y[j, :]
```

I am interested in a way to do this efficiently. Preferably the operation is vectorized, so that this can all be done with numpy very fast. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `==` and broadcasting

Comment: So, you want `kernel_arr[i,j] = 1` if row `i` of `X` matches row `j` of `Y` and `0` otherwise? Does `n_samples_x = n_samples_y`?

Comment: Yes to the first question. n_samples_x does not necessarily have to equal n_samples_y.

Comment: @MadPhysicist how would I do that in this case?

Comment: Play around with it, and when you can't get it working, update your question. I think you'll find that you learn a lot from the attempt